Sonarqube ignore rules parameter for goto statatement in the code
What is the command line line parameter that i can use to ignore the GOTO statement usage in plsql code
for example we have used below to ignore the forloop block in the code
-Dsonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e4.ruleKey=plsql:ForLoopUsageCheck
-Dsonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e4.resourceKey=**

i have tried below but it didnt work
-Dsonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e13.ruleKey=plsql:GOTOStatement
-Dsonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e13.resourceKey=**

